# error C2664 when passing derived object into constructor function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have 2 base classes. 
First one contains a list of callback functions:

```
    class BaseCallbacks {
     public:
       virtual void callback1() = 0;
       virtual void callback2() = 0;

       virtual ~BaseCallbacks(){};
    };
```

Second class just contains some logic that is common for all versions of my future specialized class:

```
class BaseClass{
  public:
    BaseClass();

    void some_function();
};
```

There's also an external class that allows me to interact with another application:

```
class InterfaceClass {
  public:
    InterfaceClass(int x, int y, BaseCallbacks &callbacks);
    virtual ~InterfaceClass(){};
};
```

One of the specialized versions of my derived class would look something like that:

```
enum TYPE{TYPE1,TYPE2};

template<bool B, TYPE T>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass, public BaseCallbacks
{
  public:
    DerivedClass(int a);

    virtual void callback1() override;
    virtual void callback2() override;
  };
```

And the following causes compilers error :

```
int main()
{
    DerivedClass<true, TYPE::TYPE1> D1(666);

    auto interface_ptr = std::make_shared<InterfaceClass>(111, 222, &D1);
}
```

The Visual Studio compiler says that: "error C2664: 'InterfaceClass::InterfaceClass(InterfaceClass &)' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'DerivedClass' to 'BaseCallbacks' ".

As far as I understand the compiler cannot figure out that my object of DerivedClass contains the required callbacks. The question is why?

I suspect that templates and multiple inheritance have something to do with it. Can you guys please shed some light on this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `BaseCallbacks &callbacks` expects reference. `&D1` passes pointer. Pass `D1` instead.

Comment: I have just realized that it's much simpler than I thought. Sorry for posting it. Should have noticed myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `InterfaceClass` constructor accepts a reference to `BaseCallbacks`:

```
InterfaceClass(int x, int y, BaseCallbacks &callbacks);
```

But you attempt to pass a pointer to `DerivedClass` (convertible to a pointer to BaseCallbacks):

```
std::make_shared<InterfaceClass>(111, 222, &D1);
```

So, to fix that, pass `D1` itself, not an address of it.

Comment: I am indeed extremely stupid. This is the consequence of sleep deprivation. Thank you.